# Flutter isolate bad performance with big list

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates

On my Flutter app i need to parse a JSON which has a list of 100k or more elements. For this reason, no not stack the UI thread, I am using Isolate to move the load of work in a separate thread. The problem is that the performance decreased a lot: without Isolate in 20/30 seconds the function was over, with Isolate it parsed just the 2% of the elements.

Since I am new to Isolate, am I doing something wrong? Or can I improve my code somehow?

```
  Future<ServiceResponse> _createServiceResponse(
    Map<String, dynamic> map,
  ) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> responseMap = {};
    List<Ean> eans = List.empty(growable: true);
    List<Article> articles = List.empty(growable: true);

    responseMap["assortment"] =
        AssortmentJson.fromJson(map).convertToObox().convertToDomain();
    if (map.containsKey("article")) {
      int counter = 0;
      for (var element in (map["article"] as List<dynamic>)) {
        String progress =
            "${(counter++ / map["article"].length * 100).toInt()}%";
        LoadingOverlay.of(context).attachText(progress);

        Map<String, dynamic> item = element as Map<String, dynamic>;
        var (article, eanList) =
            await Isolate.run(() => _createArticlesAndEanList(item));
        articles.add(article);
        eans.addAll(eanList);
      }
    }
    responseMap["articles"] = articles;
    responseMap["eans"] = eans;
    return ServiceResponse(ok: true, payload: responseMap);
  }

  static Future<(Article, List<Ean>)> _createArticlesAndEanList(
      Map<String, dynamic> articleJson) async {
    List<Ean> eans = List.empty(growable: true);

    var article = ArticleJson.fromJson(
            articleJson.convertIdToInt().convertDateFormatToAppFormat())
        .convertToObox(assignReferences: false)
        .convertToDomain();

    Map<String, int?> propertyNotAssigned = {};
    if (articleJson.containsKey("ean")) {
      eans.addAll((articleJson["ean"] as List<dynamic>).map((e) =>
          EanJson.fromJson((e as Map<String, dynamic>).convertIdToInt())
              .convertToObox(
                  assignReferences: false,
                  propertyNameToId: propertyNotAssigned)
              .convertToDomain()
              .assignArticleFromArticleList(article)));
    }

    return (article, eans);
  }
```

Comment: where do you get your input JSON from? it it some `Stream` or a huge `String` taken from somewhere?

Comment: i get the JSON from a zipped File which I receive from a network call (the JSON file is something like 80MB), and to read the content of the file I use [archive](https://pub.dev/packages/archive) to read the content of the file, so I have a String not a Stream

Comment: btw if you have only one JSON file you don't need neither `archive` nor `tar` packages: simply `gzip yourjson` and use flutter's gzip codec: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/GZipCodec-class.html

Comment: indeed, I added `GZipCodec` for on-the-fly stream decompression and while normal, not compressed JSON with 100k items was 50MB, gzip compressed resulted in 500kB and still parsing (and decompressing) of such JSON took less then second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You create a new Isolate for each element and run them one after the other. It would make much more sense to use only one isolate for everything together.
2. The biggest work in json deserialization is the conversion from a `String` to a `Map<String, dynamic>` and not the interpretation of the `Map<String, dynamic>`. Have you already taken this into account?

Comment: thanks, the 1 point actually helped, I wrapped the all function now in just 1 Isolate and now is quicker. I also removed the async from the method that was call from the Isolate, I don't know if also this helped, haven't checked

Comment: The `async` makes no difference in this situation, as you only call `sync` methods in the method.